# Android NFC tag record not read-able

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc, mifare

I have a little project to write data to Ntag 213, 215, and 216.

I success write the data using the MifareUltraLight method.
The problem is when I scan using NfcTools, the data format is different than I expected.

Here's the format that I expected.

[image]

Here's the format that I got.

[image: Expected format]

I want that when the Ntag scan, it will open the browser if the apps not installed.

I'm using Mifare method because the Ntag will be protected by password.
I tried two different way to write the data.

1. I handle the write function manually using the command for Ntag. You can see the code below

   ```
    fun writePages(msg: String, mifare: MifareUltralight) {
        val uriString = Uri.parse(msg).normalizeScheme().toString()
        val subsUri = Uri.parse(msg).host.toString()

        val encodedPayload2 = uriString.toByteArray()

        val encodedData = byteArrayOf(0xD1.toByte(), 0x01.toByte(), (subsUri.length).toByte(), 0x55.toByte()) + encodedPayload2

        val tlvEncodedData = byteArrayOf(0x03.toByte(), encodedData.size.toByte()) + encodedData + byteArrayOf(0xFE.toByte())

        var currentPage = 4
        for (i in tlvEncodedData.indices step 4) {
            var currentBlock = i + 4
            if (currentBlock > tlvEncodedData.size) {
                currentBlock = tlvEncodedData.size
            }

            val data = tlvEncodedData.sliceArray(i until currentBlock)
            var command = byteArrayOf(0xA2.toByte(), currentPage.toByte()) + data

            if (command.size < 6) {
                for (w in command.size until 6) {
                    command += 0.toByte()
                }
            }
            mifare.transceive(command)
            currentPage += 1
        }
    }
   ```
2. I tried to write the data using this simple [project](https://github.com/Cawinchan/nfc_starter_code). But the result is the same.

My question is, did I use the wrong method to write the data or something that I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you used the wrong method to write, an Ntag213 is not an Ultralight C tag (though for some basic stuff they do share similar commands)

As you want the Android OS to automatically launch the URL, the first Ndef Record in the Ndef message must of the right type of Ndef message.

On Android you don't need to encode the Ndef Record and Ndef Message yourself and write to the Tag at the protocol level you are trying to use, as the Ntag21x series are fully Type 2 compliant you can write to it using the [Ndef class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef)

An example can be seen at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70943157/2373819

Note as in this example you need to handle both formatted and unformatted Tags

Also another example of writing a Ndef Message
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921434/2373819

For create the right type of Ndef Message and Record you can use [NdefRecord.createUri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord#createUri(java.lang.String))

Comment: I used the Ndef class before, but I can't find how to set a password using this class.
Is the Ndef using similar commands to set pass on Ntag?

Comment: To set a password you would have to reconnect the Tag to the `NfcA` class and use the `transceive` method and use the write command as per the Tag's datasheet to send the write hex data to write to the Tag's memory in the correct places. That is a whole other question but is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22723250/2373819

Comment: So basically, I need 2 steps to do this?
First is writing the data that I want, then next I protected the Ntag with the password.
That means I have to tap the Ntag 2 times, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, 2 step but I don't think you need to tap 2 times, you would first `Ndef.get(Tag)` then do commands and then after `ndef.close()` I seem to remember you can do `NfcA.get(Tag)` etc to reconnect and set the password.

Comment: Thank you  so much for your help. I manage to finish it.
I will update the code on later soon.

Answer (score 0):

NTAG213 is the wrong tag: You'd have to purchase [`MifareUltralight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareUltralight) tags to use this class ... https://www.mifare.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/NXP-RFIDNFC-Portfolio_May-9-2022.pdf
Also see:
[How to set and unset password on a MIFARE Ultralight EV1 tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44395283/how-to-set-and-unset-password-on-a-mifare-ultralight-ev1-tag)

Comment: Hi, thank you. 
So I assume that if I want to use the Ntag 21x, I need to use the Ndef method to write some data?
Because I can write the pass and data perfectly, but the browser didn't open when I scanned the Ntag without the apps installed.
My coworker dev using flutter on IOS with the same method, it can produce the result that we want.